PC not powering off after screen lock has been active
I had this problem where my PC running Debian (bookworm) wouldn't fully shut down but stop at the "the system will now power off" message, at which point I had to manually power it down with the power button on the case.
I set this option in my /etc/defaults/grub and it fixed the problem:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"

However it only works if the machine hasn't gone into screen-lock while it was on. I use KDE Plasma 5 and have set the timer for "Screen Energy Saving" set to 20 minutes and "Suspend Session" turned off entirely in System Settings -> Energy Saving.
Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?
